# Need understanding of how to implement somebody else's jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, progress, radial

This is the code I want.. http://p.ar2oor.pl/cprogress/ it is exactly what i need for my project.
The download file has some code but no implementation instructions.
Having NO jquery xp I don't know how how to implement it. I used the html from the page source and linked jquery through google cdn.
Here's the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebenhafkamp/abrdz924/

```
<div class="radial">
    <div class="jCProgress" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
    <div class="percent" style="display: block;">70</div>
    <canvas width="105" height="105">
</div>
```

It's basically a compilation of code from the site, the js is purely what is written in the download link and css is the only thing I used from documentation. I can't see how it could produce what it is supposed to. Can someone shine some light on this for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the file at this link: http://p.ar2oor.pl/cprogress/jCProgress-1.0.3.js
Then do as implementation instructions suggests:

HTML

```
<div id="my-cprogress"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#my-cprogress').cprogress({
           percent: 10, // starting position
           img1: 'v1.png', // background
           img2: 'v2.png', // foreground
           speed: 200, // speed (timeout)
           PIStep : 0.05, // every step foreground area is bigger about this val
           limit: 20, // end value
           loop : false, //if true, no matter if limit is set, progressbar will be running
           showPercent : true, //show hide percent
           onInit: function(){console.log('onInit');},
           onProgress: function(p){console.log('onProgress',p);}, //p=current percent
           onComplete: function(p){console.log('onComplete',p);}
      });
```

Here's fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/abrdz924/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/abrdz924/7/)

**NOTE:** remember that you have to provide two existing images for the background ('img1' and 'img2'). In the fiddle you won't see them as the URIs I've specified is not valid.

Comment: I would mention how you changed the selector. Someone without JQuery experience should understand the targeting.

Comment: I did notice this but i was more concerned over which code to use. Thank you for pointing this out for me. Works like a charm and much easier than what i expected. Still any reason for the download source of that site to contain so much script?

Comment: @EbenHafkamp The source of the download IS the script to make that "progress-thing" happen. You just need to link to that file in the <head> section of your html pages and then call the plugin like it says in the plugin web site. The website also contains explanation for all options. The only unfortunate thing is the way the author designed the web site... I found it a bit confusing, but hey! That's me, maybe someone else likes it! :P

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying it further I finally got it to work for me :) I would vote you up but I do not have enough points.

Comment: @EbenHafkamp Glad I helped! :)